# Using Tailwind css 3 with html pages editor, which stores pages into database

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build some html pages editor on Laravel which can be using to visual editing pages. It uses Tailwind classes and stores pages into database.

Problem is that in order to use Tailwind correctly, I have to specify directories with html pages. And Tailwind will analyze the used classes during the build and "optimize" its production code:

`content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],`

But my pages are stored in the database and can be edited at any time, so classes can be different and it isn't possible to run production building every time when some page was changed.

So is it possible to run all Tailwind scripts without optimization, like it was in version 2 (it has "purge" directive what is deprecated in version 3)?

Now I'm usind [play cdn](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn), but would prefer to use right way with npm

Comment: Taliwind v2 and v3 uses different approach for optimization - while v2 gives you every possible class name, and purge unused during build process, v3 detects which one was used and inject it. So by default there is no any style for v3. But you can use CDN [script](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn) instead